# cannot ping ec2 in another vpc through peer connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, security-groups, vpc-peering

I have multiple VPC's set up, A, B and X.

I have a peered connection between A & X and between B & X, X is the Peered VPC in both cases.

I have added the CIDR Blocks for A & B to the route table & security group for x and I have added X's to A & B.

DNS Resolution & Hostnames are enabled on all 3.

My issue is A & X can ping each other just fine (using private IPs & internal Load balancers) but B & X cannot. They have Identical setups excluding the CIDR Blocks to ensure they don't overlap.

Is there something I am missing/overlooking here?

Comment: Sounds fine in theory. We'd need to see CIDR ranges, routing tables, and such. If you want more help please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Network ACLs in B, perhaps? Or, less likely, in X? In this configuration, A cannot access B *via X* by design (you can only access VPCs that you are directly peered with) but that doesn't sound like what you're reporting.  AFAIK, load balancers can never be pinged, so you'll want to test against instances.