# Cannot ping between EC2 instances in peered VPCs

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-peering

I am trying to setup a barebones VPC connection within the same AWS account.

- VPC-A and Subnet-A have CIDR: 10.200.1.0/24
- VPC-B and Subnet-B have CIDR: 10.200.2.0/24

**Each VPC contains one EC2 instance**

- 10.200.1.17 (in VPC-A, Subnet-A), let's call it EC2-A
- 10.200.2.67 (in VPC-B, Subnet-B), let's call it EC2-B

**I have added the following route to the route table that is associated with both VPC-A and Subnet-A, which should route traffic from VPC-A to VPC-B based on the CIDR range of VPC-B**

- (Dest | Target): 10.200.2/24 | PCX-123

(where PCX-123 is the ID of the VPC Peering Connection)

**The security group associated with EC2-A and EC2-B allow all inbound and outbound traffic.**

**NACL for both networks are allowing all traffic**

When I SSH into EC2-A, and try to ping EC2-B, I get timeout.

```
ping 10.200.2.67
...
...
... timeout
```

What am I missing?

FYI

1. I tried asking in stackoverflow, but it was deemed off topic
2. Yes, it in conceptually the same question as [cannot ping ec2 in another vpc through peer connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/839448/cannot-ping-ec2-in-another-vpc-through-peer-connection), but this question is dead, the asker never responded or followed up.

Comment: When you say the security groups allow "all inbound and outbound traffic", have you specifically allowed ICMP traffic, not just TCP/UDP?

Comment: @ceejayoz I've enabled both ICMP and TCP for all ports and IPs. Also, I tried other methods of verifying connectivity (I tried to SSH from EC2-A to EC2-B, and still no luck)

Comment: *"I have added the following route to the route table"* ...but did you a similar route in the other VPC to handle the traffic in the other direction?  You need symmetric route table entries.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot why? I thought route table was for routing egress traffic only??

Comment: @JamesWierzba that's true from a packet perspective.  And on the other side of the peering connection, the reply traffic is egress traffic and needs to know how to find its destination (the original source).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot -- that was the answer, thank you!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot We should put this as an answer to the question for future readers.  Would you like to do it? Since you found the solution.

Comment: @JamesWierzba thanks for the confirmation.  Answer posted.  Welcome to Server Fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VPC peering requires symmetrical route table entries -- the tables on each side of the peering connection need a route pointing across the peering connection to the other side.

> To send traffic from your instance to an instance in a peer VPC using private IPv4 addresses, you must add a route to the route table that's associated with the subnet in which the instance resides.
>
> ...
>
> The owner of the other VPC in the peering connection must also add a route to their subnet's route table to direct traffic back to your VPC.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-routing.html

(This still holds true when the same account is the owner of both VPCs.)